# Conditionally change the buttons in row according to the value in the cell in the same row

Tags: ng2-smart-table

So my scenario is that there is an "Edit" ,"Activate","Deactivate" button in the action column.
and there is a column called Status whose value will be either "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE"
Is there any way i can show and hide these action buttons according to the value in the status column[image]
i have to achieve something like in this attached screenshot

```
  settings = {
columns: {
  Status: {
    title: 'Status'
    , class: 'align-centerr'
  },
  FullName: {
    title: 'Full Name'
  },
  JobTitle: {
    title: 'Job Title'
  },
  Department: {
    title: 'Department'
  },
  EmailAddress: {
    title: 'Email Address'
  },
  MobilePhone: {
    title: 'Mobile No'
  },


},
actions: {
  edit: false,
  // custom:[{}]
  custom: [{ name: 'Edit', title: `<i  class="fa fa-edit"></i>` },
    { name: 'Activate', title: `<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>` },
    { name: 'Deactivate', title: `<i  class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i>` }
  ],

},


delete: {
  deleteButtonContent: '',
  confirmDelete: true
},
add: null,
defaultStyle: false
```

,

Comment: Hi, did you ever found the answer to your question ? I'm facing a case where I need to hide the delete action on certain rows (read-only rows).